# How to find the kernel of a transitive action?

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I am not sure about this problem. I know $gG_ag^{-1}$ belongs to $G_{ga}$ because $ gG_ag^{-1}(ga)=gG_aa=ga$, but how to prove $G_{ga}$ belong to $gG_ag^{-1}$?

What is more, I have no idea about how to prove the kernel of the transitive action?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have proven $g G_a g^{-1} \subseteq G_{ga}$, it follows by considering $g^{-1} a$ instead of $a$ also $g G_{g^{-1} a} g^{-1} \subseteq G_a$, i.e. after replacing $g$ with $g^{-1}$, also $G_{ga} \subseteq g G_a g^{-1}$.

Alternatively, you can just show $g G_a g^{-1} = G_{ga}$ directly: The left hand side consists of those elements $x$ such that $g^{-1} x g \in G_a$, i.e. $g^{-1} x g a = a$, i.e. $x g a = g a$, i.e. $x \in G_{ga}$.

The kernel of the action $G \to \mathrm{Sym}(A)$ is the intersection of all stabilizers.